# PostSharp Parameter Validation - Using RegularExpressionAttribute to find leading/trailing spaces

Tags: c#, regex, validation, postsharp, aop

I'm using PostSharp 3.1 to validate parameters of properties using validation attributes.  I would like to use [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_patterns_contracts_regularexpressionattribute) to perform the validation, which takes in a string representing the regex.  I would like to throw an exception if the string has any leading or trailing whitespace, but the string may contain spaces between words.

Prior to using PostSharp attributes, I performed a check like this:

```
if(name == name.Trim())
{
    throw new ArgumentException("name", "Name contains leading/trailing whitespace");
}
```

Instead, I want something like this:

```
[RegularExpression("[ \\s]+|[ \\s]+$")]
public name { get; private set; }
```

Which matches (i.e. these are illegal and throw exceptions)

```
"  North West"
"North West  "
"  North West  "
"  NorthWest"
"NorthWest  "
"  NorthWest  "
```

But does NOT match (i.e. these are legal)

```
"North West"
"NorthWest"
```

Unfortunately it seems my regex matches the wrong way around and I am given to understand there is no "not" operator in regex.  Also, my current expression matches (and throws exception) on the valid string `"North West"` as it matches the space in the middle.

Is it possible and neat to do this without creating a custom attribute?

Comment: Try this `(?: +.*|.* +)` regex. It will match "   North West   " and similar strings, but will not match `North West`. Is it what you need? Or is it the reversed regex you are looking for? I also guess we need to add a c# tag, right?

Comment: Ah, with that expression it is now totally the wrong way around, that is, valid strings throw exceptions and invalid strings pass... is there any way to apply a "not" to that?  Yes, I'm using C#, I have added the tag.

Comment: Then, try this one `([^ ].*[^ ])`. Or this one `\S.*\S` is even better. EDIT: You do not need `^` and `$`.

Comment: That works!  Thanks so much.  Though I don't really understand how?  I would like to accept this answer, if you could put this into an answer with a short explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex inside `RegularExpressionAttribute` must match the whole text. Here is an excerpt from the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,d22c5a73fd239490):

```
override bool IsValid(object value) {
 //...
 // We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what
 // the RegularExpressionValidator control does
 return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);
```

So, you need to add `.*` to capture anything that is in-between.

You can use

```
^[^ ].*[^ ]$
```

The regex means "match a non-space, then any number of characters other than whitespace, and non-space at the end". It also means there must be at least 2 characters to match. [Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/gR4pI9/3) where you can test this regex. Though it is for PCRE, the pattern will behave the same in C# environment (just I added `m` flag for demonstration purposes).

In order to just perform the check and allow even 1 or 0 character string, you can use look-arounds `^(?=[^ ]).*(?<=[^ ])$`. See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK5mW8/1) and pay attention to the last line where `1` is now considered a valid input.

Comment: Now, I think it should be clear :) If you still have questions, please ask.

Comment: The first one you added in the comments worked for me, `^([^ ].*[^ ])$`.  (I tested all the expressions you provided - I have these set up with unit tests so it is easy to swap them out) but none of the others seemed to work for me.  Using `\S` did not work (I did use `\\s` to escape the backslash), but in my case I'm only dealing with the space character so it doesn't matter. It also seems that I do need the start and end characters `^` and `$`.  Does the `()` mean `not`?

Comment: I also think the version with `\S` did not work correctly because `\S` also matches the end and start of string. The round brackets are just a capturing group, you do not need it at all. I also added a version with look-arounds so that `2` or `a` were valid.