# How to make multiple regular expresions in .net mvc model?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a model propery that i want a regex with either of 2 conditions.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([5]{1})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{2})[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"

[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([6]{1})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{2})[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$"
```

How can i combine these like an or condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexps differ in the first matched digit. Put `5` and `6` into a single character class (and remove `{1}` redundant quantifiers with groups - you need no capturing groups here for validation):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?[65]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$")]
```

Please note that `RegularExpressionAttribute` regex [must match the entire input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483450/3832970) string, so you may actually omit `^` and `$` anchors:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\(?[65]\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}")]
```

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5C(%3F%5B65%5D%5C)%3F%5B-.%20%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5B-.%20%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B-.%20%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%24):

[image]

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RF1Hsb/1).

If you want to avoid matching values with mismatching parentheses at the start change the pattern to

```
^(?:\([65]\)|[65])[-. ]?[0-9]{2}[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RF1Hsb/2).